Lie group cohomology: a jungle of conditions
Fix a finite dimensional Lie group $G$ (this assumption on dimensionality will be carried througouh the question). First, let us forget all the smooth structure whatsoever, and consider $G$ only as a group. In this case, central extensions of $G$ by an abelian group $A$, are classified by the second group cohomology
\begin{equation}
H^2_{gr}(G,A):=\{\omega: G \times G \to A | \; \; \omega \; \; \text{ is a cocycle} \}/\sim.
\end{equation}
So far, this is well-known and clear to me. Let us now turn, step by step, to Lie groups. First, let us put a topological structure $\tau$, which makes the tuple $(G,\tau)$ a topological group. Similarly, we look for central extensions of $G$ by $A$, where $A$ is an abelian topological group. What classifies these? Up to my knowledge, there are several notions of cohomology, but I don't know what they classify. They are given by:
\begin{equation}
H^2_{cont}(G,A):=\{\omega:G \times G \to A| \; \; \omega \; \; \text{is a continuous  cocycle} \}/\sim,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
H^2_{meas}(G,A):=\{\omega:G \times G \to A| \; \; \omega \; \; \text{is a measurable cocycle} \}/\sim,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
H^2_{loc}(G,A):=\{\omega:G \times G \to A| \; \; \omega \; \; \text{is a cocycle, which is continuous around the identity} \; \; e \}.
\end{equation}
Moreover, in the case of $H^2_{meas}(G,A)$, what are the $\sigma$ algebras with respect to which measurability is imposed?
Finally, let us turn to the full case where $G$ is a Lie group, not just a topological group. Up to my knowledge, there exist at least two definitions of Lie group cohomology:
\begin{equation}
H^2_{smooth}(G,A):=\{\omega:G \times G \to A| \; \; \omega \; \; \text{is a smooth  cocycle} \}/\sim,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
H^2_{locsmooth}(G,A):=\{\omega:G \times G \to A| \; \; \omega \; \; \text{is a cocycle smooth around the identity} \; \; e \}/\sim.
\end{equation}
Which classifies Lie group extensions of $G$ by $A$, where $A$ is assumed to be an abelian Lie group out of these two? Are there other definitions of Lie group cohomology? Which definition classifies precisely what?
The question is motivated by physics, as these central extensions with respect to a very special abelian Lie group $U(1)$ are of interest in quantum mechanics. However, I can't find a complete detailed treatment of Lie group cohomology, which treats all of my questions above. Perhaps it is already present in the literature, but in the form of articles, and my level of mathematical maturity is not high enough to grasp the subtle differences.
Thank you!

I found helpful links from Terence Tao, Karl-Hermann Neeb, and most comprehensively from Friedrich Wagemann and Christoph Wockel; this last paper appears to answer your questions and much more.
What you'd hope is that there is just a straightforward extension of the discrete theory where you replace cocycles with continuous or smooth cocycles. The issue is that continuous and smooth cocycles don't classify all extensions but only, at best, those extensions which are trivial as bundles of underlying topological spaces. This already happens for very simple extensions like the double cover
$$\{ \pm 1 \} \to S^1 \xrightarrow{z \mapsto z^2} S^1$$
which is a topologically nontrivial central extension of $S^1$ by $\{ \pm 1 \}$; the double cover does not admit any continuous or smooth sections at all, so one can't imitate the discrete theory by taking a continuous or smooth section, and this extension isn't classified by a continuous or smooth cocycle (since $S^1$ is connected, a continuous or smooth cocycle would have to be constant). More generally, an extension $K \to H \to G$ exhibits the underlying topological space of $H$ as a principal $K$-bundle over $G$, and if this bundle is topologically nontrivial the quotient map $H \to G$ will not have any continuous or smooth sections.
So if we want cocycles they have to be discontinuous in general, but then the question arises of which discontinuous cocycles still produce a group extension which is a topological / Lie group.
If you only care about Lie groups you can sidestep this issue by passing to Lie algebras, so passing from a central extension $A \to H \to G$ of Lie groups to the corresponding central extension $\mathfrak{a} \to \mathfrak{h} \to \mathfrak{g}$ of Lie algebras. Here there's no issue with taking sections and the result is that central extensions are classified by Lie algebra cohomology $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{a})$ (this is, of course, why $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{R})$ appears in the statement of Bargmann's theorem). Assuming that $A, H, G$ are all connected, this classifies central extensions $\widetilde{A} \to \widetilde{H} \to \widetilde{G}$ of the universal covers. Now one has to write down some topological condition on $\pi_1$ describing which of these extensions descend to central extensions $A \to H \to G$; this is done in Neeb's A Note on Central Extensions of Lie Groups, Theorem I.2, and there are also other references in that paper. According to Neeb the condition is that $\pi_1(G)$ acts trivially on $\mathfrak{h}$, and surprisingly to me there is no condition involving $\pi_1(A)$.
On the level of group cocycles, the motivation for looking at locally continuous resp. smooth cocycles is that we can find locally continuous resp. smooth sections of $H \to G$, maybe under some very mild hypotheses, e.g. if they're Lie groups. In other words an extension $K \to H \to G$ may not be a globally trivial principal $K$-bundle but under very mild hypotheses it will still be locally trivial. I have not worked through the details but the situation appears to be that if you use a locally continuous resp. smooth cocycle to build a central extension $H$ in the usual way you'll construct a local topological group resp. Lie group structure on $H$ in a neighborhood of the identity; then you can hope to extend this to a global structure.
From here I am just going to quote some claims from Wagemann and Wockel's 
A Cocycle Model for Topological and Lie Group Cohomology; I may not state the hypotheses they use accurately but they work in much more generality than you need if you only care about f.d. Lie groups.

If $G$ is connected, then $H^2_{\text{loc, c}}(G, A)$ (locally continuous) classifies central extensions $A \to H \to G$ where $H$ is a locally trivial $A$-bundle (Remark I.3); I think this extra condition is only needed because of how general their hypotheses are, this should always be true for Lie groups.

If $G$ is a connected Lie group and $A$ is a connected abelian Lie group, then $H^2_{\text{loc, s}}(G, A)$ (locally smooth) classifies central extensions $A \to H \to G$ of Lie groups (Remark I.3); again there's an extra condition in the text but I think it's because they allow infinite-dimensional Lie groups, this should, as above, be automatic in the f.d. case.

The continuous and smooth theories agree if $G, A$ are both Lie groups (Proposition I.7); see also Theorem 1 in Terence Tao's Central extensions of Lie groups and cocycle averaging which asserts that a locally compact central extension of Lie groups is a Lie group.

With mild hypotheses (which are certainly satisfied for Lie groups), the continuous theory also agrees with the measurable theory $H^2_{\text{meas}}(G, A)$ (Remark IV.13). Here measurable means with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebras.

If $G$ is a simply connected Lie group and $A$ is a connected abelian Lie group then $H^2_{\text{loc, s}}(G, A) \hookrightarrow H^2(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{a})$ with an image describable in terms of $\pi_1(A)$ (Remark V.14). This is relevant to your question about de Rham cohomology because it's a classical result that if $G$ is also compact and the action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{a}$ is trivial then $H^k(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{a}) \cong H^k_{dR}(G, \mathfrak{a})$; this is the de Rham cohomology of the underlying smooth manifold, not group cohomology! Unfortunately this isomorphism isn't that interesting for $k = 2$ because, with these hypotheses, both of these cohomologies are zero.


You might consider the need to use discontinuous cocycles conceptually unsatisfying and unnatural from, say, a categorical POV; fortunately Section II of the paper describes a more satisfying replacement. I think it can be motivated as follows: if $A \to H \to G$ is an extension which doesn't admit any continuous global sections then we can try to replace these with the entire sheaf of continuous local sections. Section II explains how to use this idea to write down a theory in which all of the maps involved are continuous (resp. smooth in the Lie group case). I think the resulting cohomology is basically the cohomology of the topological stack resp. smooth stack $BG$.

I thought 2) is true as well, but nlab seems to state otherwise: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+group+cohomology#definition prop in section 3. Most importantly, I can't follow the proof of nlab and I don't have a proof of 2) in finite dimensional case, so idk which to choose.

@ProphetX: that is not what the proposition says. $H^2_{\text{naive}}$ is smooth cocycles, not locally smooth cocycles. $H^2_{\text{diff}}$ is discussed by Wagemann and Wockel in Section III, or at least a topological version of it, and the isomorphism with the other good theories is Remark IV.11.

you are completely right. thanks for the effort! now it is my task to somehow understand/write out all the details to your points 1)-5) following the references, in a step-by-step pedagogical manner, to clarify this topic. This will be really difficult, but I hope I can manage. If you'd have time/be willing to help towards this, please let me know.

@ProphetX: this looks like difficult stuff, good luck! I think if you just wanted to get a handle on the (f.d.) Lie group case the easiest approach appears to be to pass to Lie algebra cohomology and completely ignore this question of trying to get cocycles at the group level which, as we're seeing, is not so easy.
